# How do you use the player-sensing command in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a door that will disappear using the `/fill x y z air` command and make it so that if certain players stand in front of it it will open. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, this is a question regarding entity coordinates testing, detecting if player is within a certain block region. It can be achieved by using volume selectors.
You see, within the entity selector (@e[nbt={},....]) there are parameters called volume selectors which include `x=, dx=, y=, dy=, z=, dz=`. These may look complicated but they are used almost the same way you use the /fill command. `x=, y=, z=` represent the starting coordinates of a block region, and `dx, dy, dz` refer to the coordinates displacement, not the ending coordinates. Ending coordinates should be `(x+dx,y+dy,z+zy)`.

Eg: I want to detect if a player is standing in a cubic region starting (10, 10, 10) to (20, 20, 20).

`execute as @a[x=10,y=10,z=10,dx=10,dy=10,dz=10] run say wowiamincube`

Eg: It is possible to limit the detection to a single block as well. Just put in the `x, y, z` coordinates and set the displacements as 0.

Now the only thing left is to insert your fill command after the /execute run code

After the player left the door zone however, use the `/execute unless` command to fill the door back up the way you opened it

Comment: Is this for Bedrock or Java

Comment: The execute shows me that it is Java.

Comment: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Target_selectors
According to minecraft Wiki, the volume selector is available to both versions of minecraft